# Updating android gradle plugin and gradle in React native projects

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Whenever I start a new React Native project and open the android part in the android studio. I get a message to update gradle plugin and gradle .

[image]

And updating them leads to erroneous imports which were previously working fine.

[image]

So, is there any limitation on gradle plugin or gradle for react-native android projects ?